# How can I create a string of random characters (as for a password...)?

Tags: c#, string, random, base64

I've written some code to generate a sequence of random characters, but it does not:

```
        byte[] sbytes = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
        String sstring;
        System.Random r = new System.Random();

        r.NextBytes(sbytes);
        sstring = Convert.ToBase64String(sbytes);

        sstring = Path.GetRandomFileName();

        sstring = sstring.Replace("=", "");
        sstring = sstring.Replace(".", "");

        textBox1.Text = sstring.ToString();
```

I believe the problem is between NextBytes and ToBase64String. I don't know how to make this work. How do you do the correct conversion to pass it to a textbox for display?

Comment: What are you trying to do? **Don't** use `Path.GetRandomFileName` for generating random strings!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generate a random password here's a [great example](http://www.obviex.com/Samples/Password.aspx). And here's [another one](http://madskristensen.net/post/Generate-random-password-in-C.aspx) which is more naive. Simply forget about the `Path.GetRandomFileName` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the random data with the filename:

```
sstring = Convert.ToBase64String(sbytes);
sstring = Path.GetRandomFileName();
```

The second statement ignores the existing value set by the first statement, so the calls to `NextRandom()` and `ToBase64String` are completely irrelevant.

What exactly are you trying to do?

EDIT: This isn't really a very good way of creating a random password. For one thing you should use `SecureRandom` rather than `Random`, and you might *also* want to avoid confusing features such as "0" and "O", and "l" and "1" looking the same. You *could* just use `Path.GetRandomFileName` on its own, but it's not really what it's designed for.

Comment: Just make a random password using ToBase64String and GetRandomFilename.

Comment: What did you mean by confusing O and 0 There is no alphabet used in the sample string in the first place...

Comment: @Nightforce2: What "sample string" are you talking about? If you use base64 from random data you can *absolutely* get a string like OOO0O0OO which in many fonts will be very hard to distinguish.

Comment: Thought you where talking about the byte string. I Gotcha now!

Answer (score 0):

if you wrote

```
sstring += Path.GetRandomFileName();
```

I'm guessing the result would be more like what you are looking for however it's only pseudo random and you should take a look at the link Darin posted